# Where does p-value should be drawn in case of two tailed Chi squared test?

Tags: statistics

Here is an illustrative example of one tailed test:
[image]

In case of one tailed test, the p-value would be area to the left of the critical value 57.336 but in case of two tailed test the p-value is doubled. How to know where to draw the second area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first chart illustrates the two-tailed situation.  You are trying to have the two tails having the same probability so you can say they cover values as extreme as or more extreme than the observation.  You can answer your question using the cumulative distribution function and its complement and inverse.

Let's take an example, where you observe the value of $65$ in your $\chi^2_{39}$-distribution; this above the median (near $39$).

- R gives `pchisq(65,39)` as $\mathbb P(X \le 65) \approx 0.994416$.
- Subtract form $1$ to get $0.005584$ as the probability of being extreme in a one-tailed sense
- Double this to get the two-tailed $p$-value of $0.011168$
- The other tail corresponds to the distribution below `qchisq(0.005584,39)` about $20.21$
- You can get this second value directly with `qchisq(1-pchisq(65,39),39)`

Incidentally, $\chi^2$ tests are typically one-tailed unless you are investigating fraud, as low $\chi^2$ statistics are typically associated with sample distributions close to the null hypothesis's prediction and so might not be seen as extreme.

Comment: Ok, so in this example if one tailed p-value is 29 and degrees of freedom - 39, then the corresponding value of Chi squared for lower tail would be 33.7?

Comment: When you say $29$ I think you mean $0.29$ or $29\%$.  Here `qchisq(0.29,39)` is about $33.7$ so yes. The two-tailed $p$-value is $0.58$ so this cannot be described as particularly extreme